# How can I set a private class instance variable to the File object used by an unmarshaller without a setter or exposing the variable?

Tags: java, callback, jaxb, event-handling

## The problem

I'm coding a Java Swing application dealing with XML files, so I'm using JAXB in order to marshal classes into documents and unmarshal the other way around.

I want to include in the class that gets marshalled a private field, that stores the backing file the class is based on (if any), in the form of a `File` object. In this way, I can determine if a backing file is in use, so that when saving via a *Save* command, if the backing file is available, I can just marshal the class directly to that file, instead of obtaining it via a "Save file" dialog.

However, it seems that with the tools available in JAXB, I cannot get the `File` object from the `Unmarshaller`, while opening it. How can I tackle the situation so that I can set that variable correctly?

*As this variable is internal, I don't want to include a setter or expose it so that other classes can't change it.*

## Background

Being aware of [class event callbacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) and [external listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html#beforeUnmarshal(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), I know I can use a class event callback to set a class instance private field either before or after unmarshalling, but it seems I can't retrieve the file object being in use by the `Unmarshaller` from inside that callback.

On the other hand, with an external listener I could get ahold of the `File` object being unmarshalled, as it would be at the same level with the `unmarshal` method call, but now the private field would either need to be public or has to include a setter in order for it to be set.

## Sample code

The following is a minimal, reproducible example, split in two files: `JAXBTest.java` and `MarshalMe.java`, both placed at the same level.

### `MarshalMe.java`

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MarshalMe {
    private File backingFile;

    public File getBackingFile() {
        return backingFile;
    }

    // Dummy function that sets the backing file beforehand.
    public void processSth() {
        backingFile = new File("dummy.hai");
    }
}
```

### `JAXBDemo.java`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBTest {
    public static void writeXML(MarshalMe me, File xml) {
        try {
            JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(MarshalMe.class);
            Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
            marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            marshallerObj.marshal(me, new FileOutputStream(xml));
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            jaxbe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static MarshalMe readXML(File xml) {
        MarshalMe me = null;

        try {
            JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(MarshalMe.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshallerObj = contextObj.createUnmarshaller();

            me = (MarshalMe) unmarshallerObj.unmarshal(xml);
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
            jaxbe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return me;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarshalMe src = new MarshalMe();
        src.processSth();
        System.out.println(src.getBackingFile());

        File meFile = new File("me.xml");
        writeXML(new MarshalMe(), meFile);

        MarshalMe retrieved = readXML(meFile);
        System.out.println(retrieved.getBackingFile());
    }
}
```

### Expected output

Running with Java 1.8 (or later, provided a JAXB library and runtime implementation is accesible), the minimal, reproducible example outputs:

```
dummy.hai
null
```

when I expect the output to be

```
dummy.hai
me.xml
```

as the class is initially written in a XML file named `me.xml` before being read back.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to set the private field without exposing it or giving it a setter: [Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html).

Using external event listeners, I can get ahold of the `File` object. Then, inside the `beforeUnmarshal` method, and after checking that I got the correct object, I use reflection to get the private field, and with the `setAccessible` method, I can now control when I get access to the field *using reflection only*.

After lifting the access checks, it's only a matter of editing the value via `set`ting it, and reinstating the checks after that.

### Relevant changes

The following snippet includes the relevant changes:

```
unmarshallerObj.setListener(new Unmarshaller.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
        if (!(target instanceof MarshalMe))
            return;

        MarshalMe me = (MarshalMe) target;
        try {
            Field meBackingFile = MarshalMe.class.getDeclaredField("backingFile");
            meBackingFile.setAccessible(true);
            meBackingFile.set(me, xml);
            meBackingFile.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {}
    }
});
```

### Including the edit in the sample program

Edit the file `JAXBDemo.java` by adding the following code:

```
// Add to the import section
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// Under this function
public static MarshalMe readXML(File xml) {
    MarshalMe me = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(MarshalMe.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshallerObj = contextObj.createUnmarshaller();

        /* Add this code vvv */
        unmarshallerObj.setListener(new Unmarshaller.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
                if (!(target instanceof MarshalMe))
                    return;

                MarshalMe me = (MarshalMe) target;
                try {
                    Field meBackingFile = MarshalMe.class.getDeclaredField("backingFile");
                    meBackingFile.setAccessible(true);
                    meBackingFile.set(me, xml);
                    meBackingFile.setAccessible(false);
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {}
            }
        });
        /* Add this code ^^^ */

        me = (MarshalMe) unmarshallerObj.unmarshal(xml);
    } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
        jaxbe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return me;
}
```

After adding the `import` and the code between the `/* Add this code */` lines, running the program again now outputs:

```
dummy.hai
me.xml
```

as expected.